# For loop to check for fonts by name according to list in array returning repeating list

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sorting, for-loop

I got most of the way there thanks to helpful folks here, but I am still scratching my head...  I have a list of fonts I need to confirm are installed on a Mac as part of a post-build check.  I want a for loop to run the system_profiler command against each item in the ${fontArray}.  If the font is not found, I want to add that $I to ${missingFonts} so I can print it on a line in the report once the script is finished.  If the font IS found, I want it to do nothing other than set values for some other variables.  Later, I check to see if ${missingFonts} is empty, if it is then it's a PASS, if not it is a FAIL and I want to echo the contents of ${missingFonts}.  Here is my current code...

```
  Var19=Fonts
fontArray=("font1" "font2" "font3")
missingFonts=()

for i in "${fontArray[@]}"; do
    system_profiler SPFontsDataType | grep "Full Name: $i" | sed 's/.*: //'
    if ! system_profiler SPFontsDataType | grep -q "Full Name: $i";  then 
        missingFonts+=( "$i" );
    fi
done

if [ ${#missingFonts[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    Val19="Fonts Installed"
    Check19=PASS
else
    Val19="Missing Fonts: ${missingFonts[@]}"
    Check19=FAIL
fi

Line19=" | ${Check19} | ${Var19}        = ${Val19} "

echo "$Line19"

exit0
```

Since these are not fonts I would expect to get:

```
 FAIL | Fonts        = Missing Fonts: font1 font2 font 3
```

Instead, I get:

```
| FAIL | Fonts      = Missing Fonts: font1 font2 font3 
font1 font2 font3
```

And when I use the actual names of fonts I KNOW are there, I just get a long list of the fonts in ${fontArray} one at a time and looping

```
realFont1
realFont2
realFont3
realFont1
realFont2
```

Until I interrupt.

I don't understand why it is printing the names twice on failure NOR why it is just printing the fonts one by one and looping through the list multiple times when they ARE found.  I am still pretty new at this and could barely manage a "Hello, world!" 6 months ago, so I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Put your code in this site: https://www.shellcheck.net/.  There are some errors in your script.  `fontArray` is not properly defined, `var19` is never used.  But you have `val19` later...

Comment: I fat-fingered the " in fontArray when I sanitized the code.  Var19 is used in a different function elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fontArray=("font1" "font2" "font3")
missingFonts=()
for i in "${fontArray[@]}"; do
    if ! system_profiler SPFontsDataType | grep -q "Full Name: $i";  then 
        missingFonts+=( "$i" );
    fi
done

if [ ${#missingFonts[@]} -eq 0 ] ; then
    Val19="Installed"
    Check19=PASS
else
    Val19="Missing Fonts: ${missingFonts[@]}"
    Check19=FAIL
fi
```